# How do you use a loop to populate an array and search the array for a specific value in Simple pseudocode

Tags: arrays, loops, pseudocode

How do you write the pseudocode to declare and populate an array with 10 elements. I need to use a loop to populate the array and search the array for the value 20. If the value is found, display a message that shows the subscript where the value is found. There may be more than one occurrence
of the value. If the value is not found, then display an appropriate message.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] array = {2, 5, 8, 20, 13, 5, 20, 3, 6, 7};
boolean isValueFound = false;

for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] == 20) {
        system.out.println("Value found at position " + i+1);
        isValueFound = true;
    }
}

if(!isValueFound) {
   system.out.println("Value not found");
}
```